# Solving error of BigDecimal in Kotlin "Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch"

Tags: android, kotlin, expression, bigdecimal, operation

I am doing this in Android Kotlin

```
val simpleInterest = ((num1*num2)*num3)/100
```

but it says
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.times(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
public inline operator fun BigInteger.times(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin

Actually my code is:

```
fun onSimpleInterest(view: View) {
        val str:String = txtDisplay.text.toString()
        val sp = arrayOf(str.split("[*+\\-\\/]".toRegex(), 3))
        val num1 = sp[0]
        val num2 = sp[1]
        val num3 = sp[2]
        val simpleInterest = ((num1*num2)*num3)/100
            buttonSI.setOnClickListener {
                txtDisplay.text = simpleInterest

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things going on here.

The `split` extension function returns a List. So `sp` is actually an Array of Lists.

Since sp's type is an Array of Lists, indexing it (`val num1 = sp[0]`, etc) is actually returning Lists, not Strings. So num1, num2 and num3 are actually `List<String>`.

What you need to do is get rid of the arrayOf and just set sp to the result of str.split. Sp will now be a List, so you can set num1, num2 and num3 to the appropriate indices, which will be Strings.

Next, convert those Strings to Ints, then you can do your arithmetic.

Finally, `simpleInterest` is an Int, but I'm pretty sure `txtDisplay` will expect a CharSequence, so convert that Int back to a String.

**Solution**:

```
fun onSimpleInterest(view: View) {
    val str:String = txtDisplay.text.toString()
    val sp = str.split("[*+\\-\\/]".toRegex(), 3)
    val num1 = sp[0].toInt() // Possible Exceptions
    val num2 = sp[1].toInt()
    val num3 = sp[2].toInt()
    val simpleInterest = ((num1*num2)*num3)/100
    buttonSI.setOnClickListener {
        txtDisplay.text = simpleInterest.toString()
    }
}
```

NOTE: There are many instances here that could throw an exception that you're not catching and handling.

If a user types less than 3 elements, then the List returned by split will have a size less than 3. So Indexing it (`sp[1]`, etc) could return IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Also on that same line, even if the user types 3 elements or more, these elements could potentially not be integers. In which case trying to convert them to Ints could return NumberFormatException.

You should handle these possibilities.

Comment: Now the error on txtDisplay.text =simpleInterest : Required Char Sequence  Found: int

Comment: @PrinceM007 yeah, I caught that before you commented. Look at my updated answer. Specifically: "Finally, `simpleInterest` is an Int, but I'm pretty sure `txtDisplay` will expect a CharSequence, so convert that Int back to a String.". The update was to this line: `txtDisplay.text = simpleInterest.toString()`

Comment: found solution to it: needs to be val simpleInterest =(num1*num2*num3)/100).toString() But still crashing on running it on my android dont know why?

Comment: @PrinceM007 yes, that works as well. In both my solution and yours, you're converting the result back to a CharSequence (which is what txtDisplay.text is expecting).

Comment: Still crashing dont know why?

Comment: @PrinceM007 Seems like a different issue is occurring. If this answered your original question, upvote/accept it, then post your new error as a new Question. Make sure you give the stacktrace and post the class/method that the Exception is occurring in.

Answer (score 0):

Float literals need to be with f after the number. I had the same problem in this line:

```
val speedKmph = ((location?.speed?: 0) * 3.6).roundToInt()
```

fixed by adding f:

```
val speedKmph = ((location?.speed?: 0f) * 3.6).roundToInt()
```